# How to organize a large Flash library?

Tags: flash

I am struggling with an enormous library in a Flash CS3 file.

I am trying to organize it by moving hundreds of symbols into sub folders, but it is too tedious to be worth doing. I select some items and then have to painstakingly drag-and-scroll the library pane to the folder I want and drop the items in there. It will take forever to get everything in the right place.

Is there a better technique, or perhaps a 3rd party app or an extension of some kind that will allow me to more easily shift stuff around inside and out of library folders? Thanks so much!

**Precision:** The question is about how to organize symbols **inside** an Adobe Flash CS3 library, not about how to organize files in general on the harddrive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are extensions to help with organizing your library.

- [Organize Library](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1034949) - organizes MovieClips, Graphics, Buttons into seperate folders, also organizes items based on their prefix, which can be added using a multiple item renamer
- [Library Renamer Commands](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1091471) - renames multiple selected library items
- [Rename Generic Items](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=1012521) - add any prefix to "Symbol X" or "Tween X" items
- [Queasy Tools](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1745524) - helps organize your library

Comment: If none of these work well for you, reply via a comment here and I'll write a JSFL command that moves the selected library items into a folder.  (you can install this command simply by copying the file to your Flash installation folder)